# Bootstrap dropdown-menu absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made vertical dropdown menu in bootstrap. Everything works just fine except one thing. The whole submenu is positioned using `fixed` attribute, and when there is some more content of page, the whole submenu is scrolling with page.

Here you have example: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ARlgRwrvQY)

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: do you want the same alignment or ok with left align? is it horizontal menu right?

Comment: the same alignment but with absolute positioning - not fixed, and yes it is horizontal menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that all the element before that dropdown are positioned `relative` which makes absolute position of width to 100% of body width difficult ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)). If you aren't looking for a JavaScript solution than with some changes to the mark-up and CSS(removing container class from `li.inline-list` , removing `col-sm-3`, changing `col-sm-9` to 'col-sm-12', postioning nav link in center and using `container-fluid` instead of `container` to wrap them) I came up with this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/l8e0iqgc4x#) .Observe  the CSS I have added

```
.top-main .dropdown-menu {
width: calc(100% + 60px);
position: absolute;
left: -30px;
}
```

Even though I could get the sub-menu to almost full length, `container-fluid` and `col-x-x` both leave 15px padding on both sides, so I had to give -30px position to left and add 60px to width using `calc` . Calc is supported by IE9+ only.

Answer (score 1):

Change in your css this,

```
 .top-main .dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 87px;
    z-index: 1000;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

This will make it stay

Comment: yes, but then the whole submenu is going to the right http://www.bootply.com/SOuqNBvgBB

Comment: So do you want Link 1.1 etc to appear in the dropdown menus or do you want it to be on the side?

Comment: The submenu should be exactly the same like now, but it should scroll with page, not stay in one position

Comment: I think the solution will have to be that you have to have a manual position on the links. Like top: right: left: and so on